# push notification for google plus integrated application

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-plus

In my application i integrate google plus and it is working fine with login and share feature
but the problem is  "the application is not getting push notification from google plus when some one share some thing on behalf of me"

i already done  all steps
http://mobiforge.com/design-development/programming-apple-push-notification-services for getting push notification and i got  notification send from parse server where my application is registered.

how can i get notification from google plus

Answer (score 0):

Google+ does not have a push API. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=8) you can star.